# Read malformed JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, unicode

I have a malformed(?) JSON file as follows:

file.json:

```
{u'results': [{u'status': u'OK', u'time': 199, u'name': u'Macap\xe1'}]}
```

I've tried using `json.loads()` to read this data, but it doesn't want to accept the unicode.
I've tried decoding with `.decode('utf-8')` but that doesn't convert the `\xe1` to the accented a.

Any help on the proper magic to decode this and parse in json would be amazing.

Thank you!

p.s. I'm working in Python 2.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not even malformed JSON, it's a Python dictionary literal. A good way to decode it is using `ast.literal_eval` (as this will make sure it can't contain anything dangerous):

```
import ast

txt = r"{u'results': [{u'status': u'OK', u'time': 199, u'name': u'Macap\xe1'}]}"
obj = ast.literal_eval(txt)
```

Comment: Ahhh, this makes sense. Quick follow up: how can I cast/declare a variable as a raw string? i.e. `text = file.read()` How can I make text a raw string?

Comment: You probably want the `repr()` of the string. This won't give you a "raw string" specifically (a "raw string" is just a way to write a string literal and once it's been parsed there is no difference between it and any other string) but it'll be escaped as appropriate for use as a string literal in Python code.